# Select data from multiple tables - laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, select, eloquent, left-join

I have two tables, one records the vehicle details and the other records the location of the vehicle on certain days.

[image: vehicle_table] [image: location_table]

I want to take the vehicle no and type of a vehicle which has a specific capacity and its location on a given date.

Ex: All the vehicles with a capacity of 9t and their locations on 2019-08-07

I have tried using joins and subqueries to get the exact output but none of them has worked.

This is my current code and it outputs multiple records for the same vehicle.

```
$vehicles = DB::table('vehicles as v')
            ->leftJoin('current_location as l', 'v.vehicle_id', '=', 'l.vehicle_id')
            ->leftJoin('locations as k', 'l.location_id', '=', 'k.location_id')
            ->select('v.vehicle_id as vehicle_id','v.type as type','v.capacity as capacity', 'k.location as location')
            ->where('v.capacity', $request->capacity)

            // ->where(function($query) use ($request)
            // {
            //     $query->where('l.date', $request->date)
            //           ->orWhere('l.date', null)
            // })

            ->get();
```

[image: output]

The expected output is a list of the vehicles with the given capacity and their locations on a given date if a location record for the given date exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can easily be achieved using **Eloquent**.

In `Vehicle.php`

```php
public function currentLocations()
{
   return $this->hasMany(CurrentLocation::class, 'vehicle_id', 'vehicle_id');
}
```

In the model `CurrentLocation.php`

```php
public function location()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Location::class, 'location_id', 'location_id');
}
```

```php
Vehicle::with(['currentLocations' => function($q) {
    $q->where('date', request('date'));
}, 'currentLocations.location'])
->where('capacity', request('capacity'))
->get();
```

Comment: I'm glad to hear that it helped!